# Move TextView only up and down

Tags: android

I would need to move TextView only up and down. I have this code, but using it you can move TextView in any direction:

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int eid = event.getAction();
                switch (eid) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
                        int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y = (int) event.getRawY();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x - 200;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y - 250;
                        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to move TextView only up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `leftMargin` assigning, that will force it to move **Vertically** only since there is no assignment for any of the horizontal vectors(**i.e.** *left* , *right*):

```
   textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int eid = event.getAction();
            switch (eid) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
                    int y = (int) event.getRawY();
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y - 250;
                    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Let's remove as well the line 
int x = (int) event.getRawX();

Comment: @user3793589 yea sure, I edited and removed it also, it has nothing to do with it in this situation.